# Redirect to Login page if not logged in to facebook

Tags: facebook

I have my app http://apps.facebook.com/svolzesocial. When you click the link and if you are not logged in to facebook still you can access the canvas. I want to avoid this. User must be logged in to facebook and must be authorised to use app.
I found this code below and its working fine for authenticating. But in the app I am using wordpress and it is not allowing users to read any article, it redirects to main app page.

```
<?php 

     $app_id = "APP_ID";

     $canvas_page = "CANVAS_PAGE";

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the redirect_uri, you probably want to set that to the url of the page originally requested rather than just the url of your canvas app.

Comment: I am doing that only, my original canvas page is located at http://fb.svolze.com and using wordpress, so when user wnats to read any psots of the site, he gets redirected to home page of the app only.